# Is using a hidden input field in a template, to pass data to a django view not secure?

Tags: html, django, forms, security, django-forms

I'm sure there's better ways of doing this but I'm just curious if this is an insecure way of passing data to the view

Template:

```
{% for object in order.all %}
...other code
<form method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form }}
<input type="hidden" name="cart_id" value="{{ object.cart_id }}">
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: In fact, I've seen http://facebook.com is using this approach, but I don't think they're using django.